# What story is the Trans-Temporal Sonic from?

Tags: story-identification, doctor-who

I have been searching everywhere for the story that the trans-temporal sonic is from. I know it is from a comic, but which one?

I also know that it is has a wood setting, which is unique to this sonic, and that there was a rather charming toy made by Character Options (which I own), but what story is this steam-punk-esque device from?

Comment: There's a [list of sonic screwdrivers](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Sonic_screwdriver_-_list_of_appearances) (that are not the Doctor's) on the fandom wiki. The only comic book reference there is from The Crystal Throne, were Vastra uses a red sonic screwdriver. Given the setting (19th century England), could this be the "steampunkesque" device you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The 'Trans-Temporal Sonic Screwdriver' is essentially a set of add-on components that fit in with an earlier set of licenced screwdrivers marketed as a "*[Personalise Your Sonic Screwdriver Set](https://merchandise.thedoctorwhosite.co.uk/personalise-your-sonic-screwdriver-set/)*" (which you'll note contains a mixture of [canon and non-canon parts](http://doctorwhotoys.net/buildyourownsonicscrewdriver.htm)) by the same company.

[image]

This item doesn't appear to come from a specific episode. Some blurb appears on the back of the box of the [Character Options toy](https://www.sfmovie-store.com/en/doctor-who/620-doctor-who-trans-temporal-sonic-screwdriver-replica-5029736043568.html), but nothing that matches any episode or comic.

> *"With the TARDIS trapped on Earth in a Trans-temporal schism, the Doctor find himself at the centre of four time zones. As with each previous time the TARDIS generates a new sonic screwdriver for the Doctor but this time it is created in the style of each time zone, Elizabethan, Victorian, Present Day and Future London."*

[image]